# Socket Programming Error In C

Tags: c, sockets

i have an infinite loop problem while im trying to send some messages from client to the server. Client has some commands like login, getusers, alias etc. and i want to check them into server. Here its my code.

## CLIENT

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> // for inet_addr
#include <string.h>
#include <zconf.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int  sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[2000], server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port        = htons(8888);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected to server\n");


    //keep communicating with server
    while (1) {

        printf("> ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", message);
        fflush(stdin);

        //Send some data
        if (send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if (recv(sock, server_reply, 2000, 0) < 0) {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

        printf("Server's reply : %s ", server_reply);
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

## SERVER

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    // for strlen
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> // for inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    // for write
#include<pthread.h>   // for threading, link with lpthread
#include "server.h"
#include "split.h"

#define MAX_CLIENT_NUMBER 100

void *connection_handler(void *);

struct User {
    char userName[10];
    int  clientSocketNo;
};

struct User users[MAX_CLIENT_NUMBER];

void getUsers() {
    printf("Number %d",userArrayIndex);

    for (int i = 0; i < userArrayIndex; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", users[i].userName);
    }
}

void addUserToArray(char userName[10], int socketNumber) {
    printf("Client logged in as %s\n", userName);
    strcpy(users[userArrayIndex].userName, userName);
    users[userArrayIndex].clientSocketNo = socketNumber;
    userArrayIndex++;
}

void loginUser(char userName[10], int socketNumber) {
    char *message = "login successful";
    write(socketNumber, message, strlen(message));
    addUserToArray(userName, socketNumber);
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc) {
    //Get the socket descriptor
    char receivedMessage[2000];  //client's message

    int  readControl;
    int  sock            = *((int *) socket_desc);

    while ((readControl = recv(sock, receivedMessage, 2000, 0)) > 0) {
        char **parsedCommand = malloc(100); //parsedClientMessage

        parsing(parsedCommand, receivedMessage, " ");
        printf("MESSAGE %s\n",parsedCommand[0]);

        if (strcmp(parsedCommand[0], "login") == 0) {
            loginUser(parsedCommand[1], sock);
        }

        if (strcmp(parsedCommand[0], "getusers") == 0) {

            getUsers();
        }

        if (strcmp(parsedCommand[0], "exit") == 0) {
            close(sock);
            return 0;
        }

    }

    if (readControl == 0) {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        clientNumber--;
        fflush(stdout);
    } else if (readControl == -1) {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    //Create Socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        puts("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port        = htons(8888);

    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        puts("Binding failed");
        return 1;
    }

    listen(socket_desc, 3);

    puts("Server started");
    c                  = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t *) &c)) &&
           clientNumber < MAX_CLIENT_NUMBER) {
        pthread_t sniffer_thread/*[MAX_CLIENT_NUMBER]*/;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if (pthread_create(&sniffer_thread/*[clientNumber]*/, NULL, connection_handler,
                           (void *) new_sock) < 0) {
            perror("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        } else {
            clientNumber++;
        }

        puts("Client connected");
    }


    if (new_socket < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its not full of my code but i think our problem in these parts. I dont understand why it happens. When i insert a break command into connection_handler's while loop, i cant send commands to the server anymore. Thanks...

Comment: You must describe your problem, not just say you have one.

Comment: In client side, running should be stop in scanf for receive new commands but it doesnt stop

Comment: As is always the case in 'running' code, try a debugger

Comment: @Berkin, how be sure that "it doesnt stop" ? When simulate that line `scanf("%[^\n]s", message);`, no problem detected = stop until <return>.

Comment: I added full of my code, can you check it again

Comment: In the `main()` of server, the `new_sock = malloc(1);` doesn't smell good. The variable `new_sock` is declared as `int *` then is used as `(void *)`. Is the allocation really needed instead of a simple `new_sock = &new_socket;` ?

Comment: actually you did not add the full code.  There is the header file: `zconf.h` that you have written but did not include. the source of it.  How are we to compile, link, debug your code when not all the code is available?

Comment: in the client, this line: `scanf("%[^\n]s", message);` is nonsense.  It is expecting to read until a newline is encountered, then the next char is expected to be a `s`.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest: `scanf("%[^\n]", message);`

Comment: this statement: `fflush(stdin);` is non-standard.  The function: `fflush()` is for moving the buffered output stream data to its' final destination.  Not for handling input streams.  Suggest using a `while()` loop that calls `getchar()` until either EOF or a '\n' is input.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `puts("Send failed");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and it is best to include the OS text that indicates why the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "send failed" );`  as that statement will properly handle the whole output

Comment: the `recv()` function can also input 0 bytes (usually means the other end of the connection has been closed.)  strongly suggest you insert a check for that condition

Comment: this line: `scanf("%[^\n]s", message);`  (after correction) will allow the input buffer to be overrun.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  strongly suggest using: `scanf("%" sizeof(message) "[^\n]", message);`

Comment: the client posted code contains some 'magic' numbers I.E. 2000.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Strongly suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names.  I.E. use an `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Server's reply : %s ", server_reply);`  The call to `read()` returns the number of bytes read. That returned value should be used to NUL terminate the `server_reply` string,  Otherwise the call to `printf()` will only quit printing when it encounters a random NUL byte in memory.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the client code does not contain any feature to exit the `while()` loop, so the code will run forever.  Suggest having a specific input string to be checked for, to cause an exit of the loop.  For instance the string: `quit`.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful,  In the client code, if the returned value is not 1, then the function failed

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. when i malloc the messages or replies, i give +1 to strlen(messsage).

So its strlen(message)+1 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Because the `'\n'` is not removed from the input, the `scanf()` function is able to reuse that last character for a next entry.

> The easiest solution to solve that problem is to clear the input
>   buffer `fflush(stdin);`.

```
while (1) {
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", message);
    fflush(stdin); // to clear \n from the buffer
    //Send some data
    if (send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
```

Comment: I added full of my code, can you check it again. Thanks